# In SharePoint 2007 How To Add WebPart into Review Of Every Wiki Page

Tags: web-part, wiki, enterprise-wiki

I want to add default webpart for every wiki pages review.
Currently I need to add webpart for every newly created wiki page.
Is there any Solution to solve this.
Thanks.